# Prepaid Statement with AWS Athena in JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, sql-injection, amazon-athena

I am new to AWS Athena. I just started using the Athena. I have integrated the Athena in java. I used the string concatenation for the building Athena query.

There might be chances of the sql Injection. I want to avoid the sql injection. As OWASP guid-line prepaid statement are use-full here.

I get the prepared stmt in the Athena document but don't know how to integrate with java?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html